# can't open a script on button click

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I have a long script webpack output, lets call it `bla.js`
In my main html file I'm trying to open `bla.js` on button click. this is how I tried to do it:

```
<body>                    
    <button class="btn-start" type="button" onclick="clickHandler()"></button>            
    <script>
        function clickHandler(){
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "scrs/bla.js";
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

but on button click nothing happens although In application tab of google chrome developer tools I can see that the `bla.js` script gets added!

And when I do it like this:

```
<body>                    
    <button class="btn-start" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='run_bla.html';">
    </button>            
</body>
```

and in the `run_bla.html`:

```
<body>                    
    <script src='scrs/bla.js'></script>     
</body>
```

it works perfectly fine! the only problem is in the second way there will be a `/run_bla.html` at the end of the url and I don't want that.

So what is wrong with the first way? How can I open the script without website url changes? any idea what is the problem? I'm stuck with this for a while...

Comment: Did my answer help you with the issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: @HeyJude didn't exactly solved it but helped me to solve it so thanks.

Comment: What was it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created your script object (stored in the `script` variable), but you haven't added it to the document.

You may add it to an HTML element using the `appendChild` function in the element, for example:

```
function clickHandler(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "scrs/bla.js";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

This will append your script to the <head> tag in the document.

Comment: oh sorry I already have the `appendChild()` in my code I just forgot to put it here in my question. I'm sorry. *eddited*

Comment: No problem. I am sorry, I have tested the script with `appendChild` and it worked fine, so I have no more clues. I dunno it is different with Webpack after compile, because it is still just Javascript and Webpack does not rely on "onload", for example (unless you have something that use "onload"). I've tested with an Webpack generated code too, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, so you probably have an error on your `bla.js` script, which prevents you from seeing the expected behavior.

You can see that in the following code: `jQuery` library is loaded dynamically, and is also executed (i.e., it's defined).

```js
function loadJQuery(){
  console.log("clickHandler called");
  console.log(typeof $ !== 'undefined'); // false
  
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
  script.onload = function() {
    script.onload = null;
    onJQueryLoad();
  }
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

function onJQueryLoad() {
 console.log("onScriptLoad called");
  console.log(typeof $ !== 'undefined'); // true
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" class="btn-start" type="button" onclick="loadJQuery()">click me</button>
```